# Using line break with chart labels is not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, coffeescript

So I have a label and a value, I would like for their to be a line break in between on my circles like this

label
value

no matter what I do though I d3 keeps them in line

labelvalue

I've used the br tag but even with that I get the same result, what am I doing wrong?

Here is the line of code I use written in coffeescript

```
.html( (d) ->
 d.label + "<br>" + d.value"
)
```

here is also a jfiddle of what I am working on (all in coffeescript) http://jsfiddle.net/nmv07mj6/1/

Comment: You can't use `<br>` tags in SVG, see http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321

Comment: are you able see the text, because of .html( (d) ->
 d.label + "<br>" + d.value"
)
call this 
.text( (d) ->
 d.label + "<br>" + d.value"
)

Comment: Yes I am able to see the text, (it shows in my jfiddle). The issue is the line break
@LarsKotthoff now sure of how I am supposed to use the wrap function or how it works.

Comment: You would set the text you want (without line breaks) with `.text()` and then `.call(wrap, maxWidth)` like in the example.